# Direct portlet access prevented by WebSphere Portal

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, jsr286, jsr

I'm trying to deploy a `JSR 286` portlet in websphere portal.

Deployment goes fine but when I try to access a resource url directly I get the following:

> Error 403: Direct portlet access prevented by WebSphere Portal

I'm very new to portlets and websphere.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard default for portal, if you install it THROUGH portal,  if you want it to be accessible I would recommend pre-deploying the portlet as a war into websphere appserver then registering it to portal.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/j2ee.dita
for more information.

To access a portlet you need to put it on a page when it is installed through portal,  all portlets are viewed in the context of being on a page